# Writing a lambda in Ruby to get the latest selling date of a collection of Tickets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda

How to write a lambda solving the following problem: I have a `Theatre` class, containing a list of `Tickets`, which in turn have the `Date` type attribute `sold_at`. Starting from the `Theatre`, I'd like to get the latest date in which any ticket was sold. In pseudo code, I would write something like:

```
Theatre.tickets.map(t -> t-due_date).max
```

I can't seem to find online how to code this. 
Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [ActiveRecord::Calculations#`maximum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-maximum):

> Calculates the maximum value on a given column. The value is returned
>   with the same data type of the column, or `nil` if there's no row.

```
Theatre.joins(:tickets).maximum('tickets.sold_at') # I assume Theatre has_many :tickets
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return you the date at which the ticket was sold last time for a specific theatre.

```
Ticket.joins(:theatre).where(theatre_id: id).order(sold_at: :desc).limit(1).sold_at
```